# C# / Linq: detected differences between two list typed

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to detect if some data changed using Linq.

I have this class:

```
public class MyData 
{
    public string Nombre {get; set;}
    public string Tipo {get; set;}
    public int Longitud {get; set;}
}
```

I have a list typed of that class which I can change the data and another one it is the copy before to change.

Typed structure:

```
List<MyData> data = new List<MyData>();

 // suppose I load data here in data variable.

List<MyData> mycopy = data;

var mydatatochange = data.Where(...).ToList();

mydatatochange

...or...

MyData info = new MyData();
info.Nombre = "aaa";
info.Tipo = "something";

data.Add(info);
```

Now I would like to see if between `data` and `mycopy` have some kind of differences.

I am trying to use it using Linq.

Comment: show some part of filling your data List. its important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code that detects added, deleted and changed items:

```
List<MyData> lst = new List<MyData>();

lst.Add(new MyData()
        {
            Longitud = 1,
            Tipo = "123",
            Nombre = "n1"
        });


        lst.Add(new MyData()
        {
            Longitud = 1,
            Tipo = "456",
            Nombre = "n1"
        });

        var cloned = lst.ToList();
        Dictionary<MyData, Tuple<string, string, int>> originalValues = new Dictionary<MyData, Tuple<string, string, int>>();

        foreach (var item in cloned)
            originalValues[item] = new Tuple<string, string, int>(item.Nombre, item.Tipo, item.Longitud);


        cloned.Remove(lst[0]);
        cloned.Add(new MyData()
        {
            Longitud = 2,
            Nombre = "aaaaaa",
            Tipo = "gggg"
        });

        var added = (from p in cloned

                     join orig in lst
                         on p equals orig into left
                     from orig in left.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where orig == null
                     select p).ToList();

        var deleted = (from orig in lst
                       join c in cloned
                           on orig equals c into left
                       from c in left.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       where c == null
                       select orig).ToList ();

        var changed = (from orig in lst
                       join c in cloned
                           on orig equals c
                       where originalValues[orig].Item1 != orig.Nombre ||
                           originalValues[orig].Item2 != orig.Tipo ||
                           originalValues[orig].Item3 != orig.Longitud
                       select orig
                            ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to check if one object equals another you can use object.Equals(otherObject), but...

In your example you do: `List<MyData> mycopy = data;` which will not be copy, but it will create pointer like object which will also change if you change data object. So in order to make it work:

1) Edit your MyData class with such code:

```
public class MyData
{
    public MyData(string nombre, string tipo, int longitud)
    {
        Nombre = nombre;
        Tipo = tipo;
        Longitud = longitud;
    }

    public MyData(MyData itemToCopy)
    {
        Nombre = itemToCopy.Nombre;
        Tipo = itemToCopy.Tipo;
        Longitud = itemToCopy.Longitud;
    }

    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public int Longitud { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Equals((MyData)obj);
    }

    protected bool Equals(MyData other)
    {
        return string.Equals(this.Nombre, other.Nombre) && string.Equals(this.Tipo, other.Tipo) && this.Longitud == other.Longitud;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = (this.Nombre != null ? this.Nombre.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (this.Tipo != null ? Tipo.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ this.Longitud;
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

2) Create clone of list:

```
List<MyData> mycopy = new List<MyData>();

data.ForEach((item)=>
    {
        mycopy.Add(new MyData(item));
    });
```

3) With this code you can do that to check if it equals:

```
var isEqual = data.Count == copy.Count;
if (isEqual)
{
    isEqual = !data.Where((t, i) => !t.Equals(copy[i])).Any();
}
```

Comment: This creates a new list containing the same objects.

Comment: Of course it does, that is what question author meant to do.

Comment: Did he? He'll end up comparing identical objects (in your query: `o` and `p` are the same objects). He has to make clones of the object before they are changed to be able to detect changes.

Comment: i said that only for added and deleted items. for changes he could do something simmilar of what EF is doing: remember original properties into a dictionary structure or a similar structure and after doing some changes, try to detect them manually.

Comment: You are right, thanks for correcting me. I will edit answer to not confuse others.

Comment: Huh, I somehow ended up mixing up answers (??). My last comments targeted @GeorgeLica's answer.

Comment: why do you use `GetHashCode` inside `MyData`? what is the meaning?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx